# Dependent expiration dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that records a timeline of information for different documents, specifically: when I send it, when I respond to it and when I need to finalise it.

In column `J`, I input the date I have sent the document given as a short date.

Column `K`, then automatically adds 15 days to `J` - giving me my response date.

```
=IF(J4<>"",SUM(J4+15),"")
```

Column `L` is my final date for when I've finished with the document.

What I'm struggling to create, is a conditional formatting formula for column `K` that reads the cells in column `J` - adds 15 days and highlights all the dates beyond the 15 days; that part is pretty simple. However, I would also like it to read the cells (in the same row) under column `L` - and if that cell is not blank/it has a date, then do not highlight column `K`. Meaning if I have finished with that document, I don't want it to run a formula to remind me to follow it up!

Below is a visual example:

[image: Text]

So in the cell `J3` reads the 27th November, add 15 days brings us to the 12th December which is before today's date (the 15th) and because there's nothing in `L3` - I would like it to mark `K3` as red.
Alternatively, in `J4` is the 28th November, therefore it's the 13th December in `K4` - however, because there's a date in `L4` I do not want it to flag `K4` in red.

Thank you, I appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to highlight the values in column `K` if the date is passed and if column `L` contains a blank, you can use the following formula for your conditional formatting:

```
=AND(K3<TODAY(),ISBLANK(L3))
```

If you already have a formula for your conditional formatting, simply replace it. If not, you add the formula the following way:

1. Select `K3` to `K8`
2. Home > Styles > Conditional formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format.
3. Type in the formula above. It will automatically apply to the selected range.

Be aware that `TODAY()` is a volatile function which might slow down your workbook if you use it extensively.